# How to put javascript in the controller using Rails 3.0.3 and Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

Can somebody please tell me how to put javascript in the controller. I tried someting like this in the sessions controller:

```
def sign_in
  if user.nil?
      @title = "Sign in"
      render :js => "alert('Invalid email/password combination.');"
  else
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user      
  end
end
```

when I tried that, the page displays in text format: alert('Invalid email/password combination.');

I don't want to use the flash message. I really wanted to use javascript alerts... Pls help...

Comment: Apparently its not working, check this gist https://gist.github.com/416046 . use javascript_tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the UJS way do this:

*in your controller.rb*

```
def sign_in
  if user.nil?    
      @title = "Sign in"    
      respond_to do |format|            
          format.js    
      end
    end    
  else    
      sign_in user    
      redirect_back_or user          
  end    
end
```

*in sign_in.**js**.erb*

```
alert('Invalid email/password combination.');
```

This will give you a nice separation of church and state.  All ruby code in the controller.rb, all javascript in the view.js.erb.

Comment: Thank you so much man.. I was having such a headache but you gave the cure... I'm so new to rails.

Comment: One quick question... If my controller name is sessions_controller.rb and the action is sign_in, what should be the name of my ujs? Is it sign_in.js.erb or sessions.js.erb? I'm kinda confused if in every action I'm gonna create a new js.erb.

Comment: should be [action].js.erb in the [controller] view folder